# Find the highest value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to go through ever value in my dataframe to find the highest value. What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

I've tried creating a for-loop to go through each item, but I'm not having much luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df.max().max()
```

or

```
df.to_numpy().max()
#df.values.max()
```

Output:

```
99
```

Setup:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(10,10)))
```

`df.max()` gets you the max of each column, then `.max()` gets you the max of those maxes.

`df.values`and `df.to_numpy()` return a np array and `.max()` takes the max value from the np array.